RegEx issue when using to highlight specific word(s)
I have a method I use to highlight text. It takes the original string and text(s) to be highlighted and returns a formatted string. I use this to highlight text(s) user wants to search in a set of files.
It worked fine until today when I tried to search for a word preceded by pipe character, '|'.
Search works fine and find all instances but highlighting does not work.
public static string HighlightKeywords(this string input, string keywords)
{
    if (input == string.Empty || keywords == string.Empty)
    {
        return input;
    }
    string[] sKeywords = keywords.Split(' ');

    foreach (string sKeyword in sKeywords)
    {
        input = Regex.Replace(input, sKeyword, string.Format("<span class=\"hilite\">{0}</span>", "$0"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }
    return input;
}

When I put a breakpoint and use a word (no pipe character) I can see the formatting is applied to that word. When I try it with a word with pipe, it looks like "hilite" class is applied to empty characters before/after each character in the line!
I search for "F08" and all F08s are highlighted;
"2024-06-24 06:24:33:494|2024-06-24 0161762152033819|F08|,"
"2024-06-24 06:24:33:494|2024-06-24 0161762152033819|<span class=\"hilite\">F08</span>|,"

I search for "|F08" and nothing is highlighted.
"2024-06-24 06:24:33:494|2024-06-24 0161762152033819|F08|,"
"<span class="hilite"></span>2<span class="hilite"></span>0<span class="hilite"></span>2<span class="hilite"></span>4<span class="hilite"></span>-<span class="hilite"></span>0 ..."


Never mind. I had to replace keyword parameter with keyword.Replace("|", @"|"); Works fine now. Sorry, jumped the gun :)
